# Fix play function

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am try to develope a Macro Recorder in html and javascript , my all functions seems to work correct , but wen i press play button its not work also i have try debug and there is no errors , i cant find any error or some thing wrong , how can i fix this bug.
Here is my current code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Macro Recorder</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="start">Start Recording</button>
    <button id="stop">Stop Recording</button>
    <button id="play">Play Recording</button>
    <button id="save">Save Recording</button>
    <button id="load">Load Recording</button>
    <script>
      var events = [];
      var isRecording = false;

      document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", function() {
        isRecording = true;
        events = [];
      });

      document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() {
        isRecording = false;
      });

      document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
        if (isRecording) {
          events.push({
            key: event.key,
            charCode: event.charCode
          });
        }
      });

      document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", function() {
        events.forEach(function(event) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            var event = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {
              key: event.key,
              charCode: event.charCode
            });
            document.dispatchEvent(event);
          }, 500);
        });
      });

      document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var data = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(events));
        var downloadAnchorNode = document.createElement("a");
        downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("href", data);
        downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("download", "events.json");
        document.body.appendChild(downloadAnchorNode);
        downloadAnchorNode.click();
        downloadAnchorNode.remove();
      });

      document.getElementById("load").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("type", "file");
        input.addEventListener("change", function() {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function() {
            events = JSON.parse(reader.result);
          };
          reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
        });
        input.click();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am try to develope a Macro Recorder in html and javascript , my all functions seems to work correct , but wen i press play button its not work also i have try debug and there is no errors , i cant find any error or some thing wrong , how can i fix this bug.

Comment: If we are hunting for a bug in your functions, do we need to see your WHOLE file?  Do we need to see your styling declarations?  Please form a [mcve] so that contributors have an easier time identifying the problem.  Why do we need to see `start`, `stop`. `load`, and `save`?  Did you eliminate them as possible causes -- by commenting them out while testing?  If they are not contributing to the issue, remove them from your question.  Do not repeat portions of text as a means to get your code-dump question published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `keypress` event (which is deprecated, please don't use it) you store the `key` property of the event, but then in the `play` function you expect the `code` property to be present, so that's why it doesn't work.

You should learn to use the debugger, you would have found the problem immediately.

Comment: i have change the code and try  to fix the play script i can start and stop and save but wen play button ,nothing happen i saved the event to file and the events are there , here is what its come on the saved file [{"type":"click","x":125,"y":42},{"type":"click","x":356,"y":240},{"type":"click","x":459,"y":391},{"type":"click","x":841,"y":377},{"type":"click","x":993,"y":253},{"type":"click","x":1032,"y":214},{"type":"click","x":1076,"y":377}]

Comment: Your `play` function only creates "keypress" events, why would it work with "click" events?